# Number of invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

A is symmetric linear map $R^{2n} \rightarrow R^{2n}$. Characteristic polynomial of A is $(\lambda -1)^2 \cdots (\lambda - n)^2$. How many invariant subspaces does A have?

Choices: $2n; 2^n; 2^{2n}$; infinitely many.

What I deduced: A has n different eigenvalues equal {1 ... n}, each twice. Also, all of them are real due to the fact that A is symmetric. What to do next?

Comment: It would be helpful if to know a bit about your background when writing an answer. Do you know the spectral theorem? Do you know the invariant factor decomposition of a module?

Comment: No, sorry. Is it possible just to give intuition behind the proof?

Answer (score 1):

If you take the standard basis and represent $A$ as a $2n \times 2n$ matrix with respect to this basis, then $A$ is a real symmetric matrix. It is a fact that such matrices are diagonalizable. In other words, there is a change of basis so that $A$ becomes a diagonal matrix with respect to this new basis. Now, if you think about what multiplication does to a basis vector in this diagonal basis, you can see that the basis vectors are eigenvectors. Thus, we have 2n different eigenvectors. The 1-dimensional subspace that is generated by a given eigenvector is an invariant subspace and so we have 2n invariant subspaces.

But wait! If you take the subspace spanned by any combination of eigenvectors, then you can show that this will also be invariant. So the total number of invariant subspaces is at least $2^{2n}$.

But wait! Lets consider the two eigenvectors $b_1, b_2$ with eigenvalue 1 in the diagonal basis. Then $A(b_1)=b_1, A(b_2)=b_2$. But also, for any $r, s \in \mathbb{R}$, $A(rb_1+sb_2)=A(rb_1)+A(sb_2)=rb_1+sb_2$. Thus, any linear combination of $b_1, b_2$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. Then the subspace generated by any eigenvector gives an invariant subspace. We can easily pick infinitely many of these so that no two give the same subspace. For instance $b_1+mb_2$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}$ so that we have infinitely many invariant subspaces.

Hopefully this gives some intuition as to the answer to the problem and helps you think about why the other answer choices were given.

Comment: Hi, Alexander. As far as I understand, you used only symmetricity of matrix. So the condition that characteristic polynomial has specific form is irrelevant for number of invariant subspaces in this problem. Am I correct?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is important! Looking back at this answer, maybe it's not so clear what I meant, but think of this. The matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ has infinitely many invariant subspaces since any 1-dimension subspace is invariant but $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ has only two proper nontrivial invarint subspaces: that spanned by $(1,0)$ and that spanned by $(0,1)$. In other words, we need the specific characteristic polynomial above because we need to have the repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

- Consider the case $n = 1$.
- What is $A$ in this case?
- What are its invariant subspaces?
- How may invariant subspaces are there?